# snakemake, how to build a loop for two independent parameter

Tags: python, loops, snakemake

I want to loop snakemake above two different wildcards, which - I think - are somehow independent from each other.

In case that there is already a solved threat for this case, I would be happy for a hint. But so far I'm not sure what the correct terms are to look for what I want to do.

Let's assume my pipeline has three steps. I have a set of samples which I process in each of those three steps. Put in the second step I deploy an extra parameter to every sample. In the third step now I have to iterate through the samples and the associated parameter.
Because of this structure, I think it's not possible to solve this with a dictionary structure.

To picture the case I made this simplification of my files and rules:
The config file:

```
config.yaml

samples:
- a
- b
- c
- d
threshhold:
- 0.5
- 0.1
- 0.2
```

A scheme of my snakefile. It pictures the exact structure and naming of snakemake operations. At least the naming is simplified. (I added the tools I actually use in brackets but I think that's not essential for understanding.)

```
rule all: 
    input: 
      expand("{sample}.bam", sample=config["samples"]),
      expand("{sample}_{param}.bed", sample=config["samples"], param=config["threshhold"])

rule first: # (samtools view)
    input: 
       "{sample}.sam"
    output:
       "{sample}.bam"
    shell:
       "<somecommand> {input} {output}"

rule second: # ( macs2 callpeaks; Of course, there are multiple outputs but they only vary in their suffix))
    input:
       "{sample}.bam"
    output:
       "{sample}_{param}.bed"
    params:
       out_name="{sample}",
       threshhold="{param}"
    shell:
       "<somecommand> {input} -n {params.names} -q {params.threshhold}"
```

So now I have a list of files looking like this:

- a_0.5.bed
- a_0.1.bed
- a_0.2.bed
- b_0.5.bed
- b_0.1.bed
- b_0.2.bed
- ...

In my third rule I want to do intersections of different samples with the same param. Like: *a_0.5.bed x b_0.5.bed* and *c_0.5.bed x d_0.5.bed* and get the output like *ab_0.5.bed*, *ab_0.1.bed*, *cd_0.5.bed*...

My first attempt was this:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("ab_{param}.bed", param=config["threshhold"])
        
rule intersect_2: # (bedtools intersect)
    input:
        a=expand("{sample_a}_{param}_peaks.narrowPeak", sample_a=config["samples"][0], param=config["threshhold"]),
        b=expand("{sample_b}_{param}_peaks.narrowPeak", sample_b=config["samples"][1], param=config["threshhold"])
    output:
        ab="intersect/ab_{param}.bed"
    params:
        threshhold="{param}"
    shell:
        "bedtools intersect -u -a {input.a} -b {input.b} > {output.ab}"
```

Well this doesn't work because now the input are all the different parameters files at once.

I think I need more and a different loop structure here. Maybe even some extra python loops around the rule or something? But since I have no programming experience at all and I'm just getting started to go into those things step by step, I couldn't figure out by now where to start or which loop is required for this.

Summary:
With the given config file I'd like to archive a folder which is filled with different combinations of the samples with the same parameter. So to end up with a list which looks like this:

- ab_0.5.bed
- ba_0.5.bed
- cb_0.5.bed
- ca_0.5.bed
- abc_0.5.bed
- bca_0.5.bed
- cba_0.5.bed

And those combinations too, for all the other parameters.

I would really appreciate any help and every hint that helps to understand what I exactly want to do there and how I can build this.

EDIT:
Would maybe a completely restructured config file would help? Where the samples are already pre-combined? Maybe like this: (let's assume that s1, s2 and so on are standing for the real (and long) sample name)

```
config.yaml
samples_combinations:
- s1 : s2
- s3 : s2
- s3 : s1
```

I still have to rename it...
But I don't really like the idea. My aim is to build something which is easily applicable  and straight forward without as much manual refinement, Especially because you can have way more than just three samples in this case which have to be combined in multiple ways.

Answer (score 3):

I think you almost got it. You can achieve what you want with simple wildcards. Remember that `expand` is used to create lists. Keep it simple:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("intersect/ab_{param}.bed", param=config["threshhold"])

rule intersect_2: # (bedtools intersect)
    input:
        a="{sample1}_{param}_peaks.narrowPeak",
        b="{sample2}_{param}_peaks.narrowPeak"
    output:
        ab="intersect/{sample1}{sample2}_{param}.bed"
    shell:
        "bedtools intersect -u -a {input.a} -b {input.b} > {output.ab}"
```

Just some notes about this:

- It is confusing to use wildcard names (or input/output names) that are also real names of your samples.
- It is quite dangerous to put two or more wildcards in a row without separators

All put together, I would write something like this:

```
import itertools

sampleCombinations = [s[0]+"-"+s[1] for s in list(itertools.combinations(config["samples"],2))]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("intersect/{pairOfSamples}_{param}.bed", pairOfSamples=sampleCombinations, param=config["threshhold"])

rule intersect_2: # (bedtools intersect)
    input:
        s1="{sample1}_{param}_peaks.narrowPeak",
        s2="{sample2}_{param}_peaks.narrowPeak"
    output:
        "intersect/{sample1}-{sample2}_{param}.bed"
    shell:
        "bedtools intersect -u -a {input.s1} -b {input.s2} > {output}"
```

`itertools.combinations` will make pairs out of your samples defined in config.

The `sampleCombinations` list will hold all possible pairs of samples separated by a hyphen (ie: "a-b", "b-c", "c-d" etc...). This might break if your sample names contain hyphens, as snakemake will not be able to reconstruct the wildcards well (`{sample1}-{sample2}`). It that case, choose another separator.

**EDIT** following OP's comments:

*Sorry in my rule all, I had forgotten to put the `intersect` folder output.*
*I also forgot the `_{param}_` par in the input files*

Let's say you have a config file like this:

```
samples:
- name: very_long_name_a
  shortName: a
- name: very_long_name_b
  shortName: b
- name: very_long_name_c
  shortName: c
threshhold:
- 0.5
- 0.1
- 0.2
```

then, you can use something like this:

```
import itertools

configfile: "config.yaml"

longNamesList = [s["name"] for s in config["samples"]]
shortNamesList = [s["shortName"] for s in config["samples"]]
shortToLong = {s["shortName"]:s["name"] for s in config["samples"]}

sampleCombinations = [s[0]+"-"+s[1] for s in list(itertools.combinations(shortNamesList,2))]

rule all:
        input: expand("intersect/{pairOfSamples}_{param}.bed", pairOfSamples=sampleCombinations, param=config["threshhold"])


rule intersect_2: # (bedtools intersect)
    input:
        s1=lambda wildcards: shortToLong[wildcards.sample1]+"_"+wildcards.param+"_peaks.narrowPeak",
        s2=lambda wildcards: shortToLong[wildcards.sample2]+"_"+wildcards.param+"_peaks.narrowPeak"
    output:
        "intersect/{sample1}-{sample2}_{param}.bed"
    shell:
        "bedtools intersect -u -a {input.s1} -b {input.s2} > {output}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Sounds reasonable so far. I'll test it right away. But there is one more thing. Maybe it indeed got lost in the example:

The names of the samples are quite long. So I wanted the name of the output file really want to be "ab.bed". Than there I have the problem that I can't define sample1 and sample2 in the rule all. Is there a way to do it anyway?

Comment: Regarding how to name the output files, I tend to separate elements of file names by underscores, and use wildcard constraints to help snakemake parse things correctly. It  generally works well, but sometimes makes things hard to debug when snakemake  doen't find how to produce some file due to wildcard constraints.

Comment: hm, unfortunately this doesn't work right now. Was it intended, that "rule all" is different to the output? But even with this fix it raises the error I feared above that in this version there is no way to define "sample1" and "sample2". 

When I add "expand" to input to do this, I also have to give the param definition which leads to the whole list and not just one file.

Comment: EDIT: I think the approach with itertools can work as long as I find out it will also give me the single values, or? But than there is still the problem with the naming. Can I solve this than when I have my config file changed to something like " sample1 : a, sample2 : b" ?

Comment: @VcFbnne if you want to change the name of the samples in the Snakefile, you have to keep, with some kind of structure (dict, list, tuple or else), the original sample name and the new name. Yes, a sample name corresponding to a letter in the config file would be the best !

Comment: yea ok. I still can't come with an idea how to associate s1 and s2 only with one file per round and not the whole param list.

Comment: yea - pretty much close! Only thing is, that I don't iterate through the params with the input files. I tried to figure out my self how to add this to the input function. But I just can't get the clue. I  tried: 
s1=lambda wildcards: shortToLong[wildcards.sample1]+[p for p in config["threshhold"]]+"_peaks.narrowPeak" 

but this raises  "can only concatenate str (not "list") to str"
Can you give me one last hint for this, please?

Comment: @EricC. can you give me a hint, pls?

Comment: @VcFbnne Sorry I forgot the `_{param}_` part in the input files. If I understood What you're trying to achieve, it should work. Don't forget that it is `rule all` that triggers the `rule intersect_2` so if you ask `intersect/a-b_0.5.bed` and `intersect/a-b_0.1.bed` in `rule all`, `rule intersect_2` will be run twice.