# Providing a list of paired files as input for Snakemake

Tags: list, input, snakemake

I have done a simple pipeline where I take a couple of files, merge them (well not really, but let's pretend they are merged) into one whose filename is a simple combinations of the two (file1_file2.output) and perform some operations. The pipeline works perfectly if I manually provide the filenames for both file1 and file2, but what I really what to do is something like this:

Let's pretend I have 5 files **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** and **E**. I want to run the pipeline for those pairs: **A-D**, **B-D** and **C-E** and this is the Snakefile

```py
rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/{file1}_{file2}.output")

rule Paste:
    input:
        F1="{file1}",
        F2="{file2}"
    output:
        out="output/{file1}_{file2}.output"
    shell:
        "paste {input.F1} {input.F2} > {output.out}"
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the real names of the target files in rule all. Then use the wildcards to get the input files. It would look like this:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/{combination}.output", combination=["A_D","B_D","C_E"])

rule Paste:
    input:
        F1="{file1}",
        F2="{file2}"
    output:
        out="output/{file1}_{file2}.output"
    shell:
        "paste {input.F1} {input.F2} > {output.out}"
```

Please note that using a poor separator like "_" might mess up the wildcards determination if your input files (A,B,C,D,E) also contain "_". I would use something you are sure will not be used in a file name (ie: "__", "_-_", or anything appropriate)

Comment: Thank you Eric. Yes, I was thinking about having the real name in the rule all, but I just can't figure out how to assign to those {file1} and {file2} the real file names. Oh and yeah, I have only used a simple underscore as the separator just to keep the example as simple as possible, in the real pipeline I have something else.

Comment: @AGarofoli Why don't you use the real file names for file 1 and 2? In this example, "file1" should be "A" and "file2" should be "D" for "output/A-D.output". But you can set the input like `F1="/full/path/to/my/data/{file1}.whatever"`. This will keep the real names of the file. The other way is to use a structured file. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491104/snakemake-how-to-build-a-loop-for-two-independent-parameter/56491867#56491867